# `wget` raises a HTTPError

Tags: python-3.x, wget, urllib, http-error

I have a large json file (2.5GB) that contains links to download some documents. I wrote a python script to download all these documents:

```
with open("arxiv_2010_to_2016.json") as  f:
    X = json.load(f)

for article_id in X:
        link = X[article_id]["link"] + ".pdf"
        wget.download(link, out="docs")
```

There are thousands of such documents references in the json file. After successfully downloading 1204 documents, the script crashes with a `HTTPError` :

> File "/home/imane/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wget.py", line
>   526, in download
>       (tmpfile, headers) = ulib.urlretrieve(binurl, tmpfile, callback)   File "/home/imane/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line
>   248, in urlretrieve
>       with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:   File "/home/imane/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in
>   urlopen
>       return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "/home/imane/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in
>   open
>       response = meth(req, response)   File "/home/imane/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in
>   http_response
>       'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)   File "/home/imane/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 564, in
>   error
>       result = self._call_chain(*args)   File "/home/imane/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in
>   _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)   File "/home/imane/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 756, in
>   http_error_302
>       return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)   File "/home/imane/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in
>   open
>       response = meth(req, response)   File "/home/imane/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in
>   http_response
>       'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)   File "/home/imane/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in
>   error
>       return self._call_chain(*args)   File "/home/imane/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in
>   _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)   File "/home/imane/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in
>   http_error_default
>       raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

How can I run the script and download all the docs without the script crashing ?
I am running Fedora 28, python 3.6.6, wget 3.2

Comment: Seems to be a server error, the server is forbidding the request. Maybe there is a limit in the number of files you can download per IP. Or you cannot download that file because it is protected. You could try to catch the exception and continue with the others. If all files failed after this one, you know there is a limit and you would need to contact them or use a VPN to change your IP every x files.

Comment: well, http requests may raise exceptions.. you need to suppress it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some urls cannot be reached -

You can use a simple try/except if I am understanding your problem correctly -

```
for article_id in X:
    link = X[article_id]["link"] + ".pdf"
    try:
        wget.download(link, out="docs")
    except HTTPError:
        continue
```